# FOSUserBundle add properties

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i've extended FOSUserBundle with my custom User Entity in this way:

```
<?php

namespace Hu\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     protected $id;

     /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fname", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
     private $fname;

     // other fields...


    /**
     * Set fname
     *
     * @param string $fname
     * @return UserEntity
     */
    public function setFname($fname)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
     public function getFname()
     {
         return $this->fname;
     }

     public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // ...
        $this->fname = setFname($fname);
    }
}
```

But when i try to load the /register route or to add a new user by:
    php app/console fos:user:create

Symfony returns me:
    FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined function Hu\UserBundle\Entity\setFname() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/sfprojects/quattro/src/Hu/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

What's wrong in the constructor? What i miss?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2):

`setFname` isn't function, but it is method in your class.

so to execute it you need use `$this->setFname($fname)`.

Also in constructor you shouldn't run methods like setters or getters (if they don't do anything except set variable or get variable)

Your constructor should look like:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->fname = $fname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the commande " php app/console fos:user:create " uses the setters of the entity User to affect data inputs from the terminal ( in the same way that Forms uses them to affect the data to an object from the < input ... > tag ) .
You can add setters for all the fields you added to your User class to solve this problem

exemple :

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="fname", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $fname;

public function setFname($fname) {
    $this->fname = $fname;
}
```